# Passing handles INTO a anonymous function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-guide

I'm pretty stuck on this bit of code in which I'm trying to register where someone is clicking on a image(on a axes in a GUI). Right now I'm registering the mouse clicks with:

```
imageHandle = imshow(movImg,'parent',handles.axes1); 
set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@imageClickCallback);


function imageClickCallback(objectHandle,eventData)

axesHandle = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint');
disp(coordinates);

X = coordinates(1); 
Y = coordinates(2);

%handles.markedFrames(handles.markedIndex).x = X;
%handles.markedFrames(handles.markedIndex).y = Y;

%%Increment the index were on in the marked list
%handles.markedIndex = handles.markedIndex +1;
%guidata(objectHandle,handles);
```

The problem is that I want to be able to store the coordinates of each click into an array that is able to be passed around to all the call backs of my GUI. I tried putting in handles as a parameter of the anonymous function but it doesn't really work, I tried globals but they get really messy, and I also tried creating another whole function as a different approach:

```
function clickerCall(handles)

handles.markedFrames(50) = struct('x',[],'y',[],'frame',[]);
handles.markedIndex = 1;
[handles.markedFrames(handles.markedIndex).x,handles.markedFrames(handles.markedIndex).y] = getpts(handles.axes1);
handles.markedIndex = handles.markedIndex+1;
disp([handles.markedFrames.x]);
updateAxes(handles);
```

This also gets tricky because I'm not sure where to call it from, and I also keep getting the error: *'Attempted to access pt(1,1); index out of bounds because size(pt)=[0,0].'* 
SO long story short, any help on how to use any of these approaches would be AWESOME, I'm really stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the anonymous function ? I see only `Callback` functions. Are you asking how to [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html?refresh=true)

Comment: @Hoki The anonymous function is in the first chunk of code. It's the `set(imageHandle,'ButtonDownFcn',@imageClickCallback);`, with `imageClickCallback` being the function itself. Ideally I would use this, but I need to be able to pass in `handles` so that I can take the coordinates and use them in all the callbacks, for later things like drawing points where I clicked on the image axes.

Comment: You are talking about a [function handle](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) assigned to a callback, not an anonymous function. Have you read the link in the precedent comment ? For your case I recommend specifically the chapter: [Store Data as Application Data](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html?refresh=true#bt9p4t0).

Comment: Hey Hoki, I tried this but I'm not sure what the Obj would be? Isn't it supposed to be a graphical object? In my case, `imageClickCallback` isn't attached to a specific graphical object in the GUIDE GUI. Also, I'm trying to store this data in `markedFrames` which is a predefined struct array at the top of the program, which also happens to be attached to handles so the other functions have access to it. It seems like this method messes that up or am I wrong? Thanks for the help though, this is as far as I've gotten.